# Voter Turnout Discrepancy

Tags: united-states, election, presidential-election

Another question about the 2016 US presidential election.  I was comparing the voter turnout reported for Wayne County, Michigan by the [State Board of Elections](http://miboecfr.nictusa.com/election/results/2016GEN_CENR_TURNOUT.html) with the voter turnout reported by the [County Board of Elections](http://waynecounty.com/clerk/1609.htm). The first reports 788459.  The second reports 802195.  Am I comparing apples to oranges?  Naively, such a vote difference could correspond to several thousand lost votes for Clinton.  (I also noticed a discrepancy in voter turnout totals for Oakland County in 2012 although that difference seems less critical.)

Comment: I would contact the entities above and ask them about their canvassing methods.  They should be able to explain the discrepency

Comment: Given the current recount efforts, I'm assuming everyone there is too busy to answer questions anytime soon.  I was hoping someone with relevant experience might be able to either confirm that there was a screw-up or that  the difference represents something like provisional ballots that were deemed invalid.

Comment: I received a suggestion from the Michigan State Board of Elections about the Oakland 2012 case.  They don't know for sure (not encouraging), but it may be due to split precincts.  The idea is that a precinct may straddle county lines and that voters from county A may vote in county B.  County B may then report the total number of voters including those from county A while the state may only report the county B voters that voted in county B.  Here is a discussion of split precincts: http://electls.blogs.wm.edu/2012/01/25/va-split-precincts-a-state-divided/

Answer (score 2):

The figures you cite are incorrect.  Per [this link](https://www.waynecounty.com/documents/clerk/1611BLTL.pdf), coming directly from Wayne County, show the same number of ballots cast as the Secretary of State's county total: 788,459. It's obvious that the numbers from the county that you're using reference something different than actual ballots cast.

Comment: Re _"The figure**s** you cite **are** ... the number**s** from ..."_:  there's no need for plurals.  The OP cites *two* figures, one of which you appear to saying is authoritative.

Comment: It looks like the link I used for the second statistic is broken.  If you click on the text above, you get redirected to the main page.  I guess Wayne County "fixed" the problem at some point.  I wish I knew what the original issue was.

Comment: You can access the broken link if you use the WayBack machine: https://archive.org/web/.  I would be happy to hear if you have any insight into what happened.